# Not able to see Firebase analytics firing in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm a new programmer. I've launched my first app on the Apple App Store and I incorporated Firebase to do user authentication. But I'm completely new to Firebase, so I thought that incorporating Firebase as a Swift Package would automatically enable Firebase Analytics such as in_app_purchase or first_open. I've noticed that those events don't seem to be registering even though I have users using the app. (screenshot of the firebase analytics page in the link below)

[image: Firebase screenshot]

Would anyone know what I'm missing here? Any guidance would be appreciated since I'm new to this.

Comment: Double check your config file n your project with App ID correctly mapped with the one in your Firebase console (Project Overview>Project Setting>General). You could check the DebugView to verify if it is indeed logging.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I'm afraid not. :( Do you have any guidance for me?

Answer (score 6):

The most common cause is not adding the `-ObjC` to the `Other Linker Flags` options in the Xcode `Build Settings` tab. More details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/SwiftPackageManager.md.